Storybook and NX: One main Storybook instance for all projects
I have 7 angular apps inside nx monorepo, those apps use visual components stored in shared-ui lib. What I need to achieve is to implement a new project with storybook, and then inside that new project generate all stories for those visual components. The purpose is to have that project deployed with specific url in order for UX guys to see at any time all components already implemented.
So for example if i have project 1, and shared-ui lib, i need to have story book project to show shared-ui lib components.
Is that posible? Thanks
I tried with official documentation but as far as i get, the documentation shows the implementation of a new library for story book. And thats not what i want, I want new project to show components already done and to help UX guys to understand what is currently done.

Yes, the storybook-host library suggested by the docs has a build-storybook target. Then you can deploy the static output. https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/one-storybook-for-all

Ok, thanks for your answer, I'm looking into the link you shared. You mean to BUILD and publish the output?

yep, output after build will be in dist/storybook/storybook-host or similar, can use ci/cd such as github actions to publish. I'll stick example in an answer

Further to my comments, indicative example of a github action to deploy
Adapted from https://github.com/nrwl/ci/blob/main/.github/workflows/nx-cloud-main.yml
name: 'Chromatic Deployment'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_storybook:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NODE_VERSION: 20.5.1
      PNPM_VERSION: 8.6.9
      STORYBOOK_BUILD_DIR: dist/storybook/storybook-host
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # We need to fetch all branches and commits so that Nx affected has a base to compare against.
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Derive appropriate SHAs for base and head for `nx affected` commands
        uses: nrwl/nx-set-shas@v3

      - name: Print BASE and HEAD
        run: |
          echo "BASE: ${{ env.NX_BASE }}"
          echo "HEAD: ${{ env.NX_HEAD }}"

        # Set up the specified Node.js version
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

      # Install pnpm with exact version provided
      - name: Install PNPM
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2.2.4
        with:
          version: ${{ env.PNPM_VERSION }}

      - name: Get PNPM cache directory path
        id: pnpm-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "dir=$(pnpm store path)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Use the node_modules cache if available
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.pnpm-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ matrix.node-version }}-pnpm-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ matrix.node-version }}-pnpm-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install --prefer-offline --frozen-lockfile

      # Build storybook host
      - name: Build Storybook
        run: pnpm exec nx run storybook-host:build-storybook

      - name: Deploy to Chromatic
        uses: chromaui/action@v1
        with:
          storybookBuildDir: ${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.STORYBOOK_BUILD_DIR }}
          projectToken: ${{ secrets.CHROMATIC_PROJECT_TOKEN }}

